# initilize the bash input argument when nothing is given | Error

Tags: python, json, bash, rest, curl

I have a following bash script which is a REST API for a national library using `curl` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ARGUMENT in "$@"
do
    echo "$ARGUMENT"
     KEY=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=)

     KEY_LENGTH=${#KEY}
     VALUE="${ARGUMENT:$KEY_LENGTH+1}"

     export "$KEY"="$VALUE"
done
echo "ARGUMENTS COUNT : " $#
echo "ARGUMENTS LIST  : " $*

out_file_name="newspaper_info_query_${QUERY// /_}.json"
echo ">> Saving DIR: $PWD/$out_file_name"

if [ -z "$ORDER_BY" ]; then ORDER_BY="${ORDER_BY:-}"; fi # returns ERROR when no input is provided!

curl \
-v 'https://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/rest/binding-search/search/binding?offset=0&count=10000' \
-o $out_file_name \
-H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
--compressed \
-d @- <<EOF
{   "orderBy":"$ORDER_BY",
    "query":"$QUERY"
}
EOF
```

Then, I run the aforementioned bash script in python:

```
import subprocess

def rest_api():
    subprocess.call(['bash', 
                     'my_file.sh',
                     'QUERY=freedom', # mandatory, always provided!
                     'ORDER_BY=RELEVANCE', # optional, if comment: ERROR!
                    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rest_api()
```

`ORDER_BY` argument gets the following inputs: `RELEVANCE, TITLE_ASC, TITLE_DESC, AUTHOR_ASC, AUTHOR_DESC, DATE, DATE_DESC` or simply nothing.

It works when I use either one of those inputs in my python script as the input to the bash script to retrieve a json file with information.

To handle no input case, e.g., initialize `ORDER_BY` as empty or nothing , I have added `if [ -z "$ORDER_BY" ]; then ORDER_BY="${ORDER_BY:-}"; fi` to set ORDER_BY with no parameter, e.g., empty! However, It does not work and returns this long error in my saved json `out_file_name`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fi">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
    <title>Digitaaliset aineistot - Kansalliskirjasto</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
    <meta name="copyright" content="Kansalliskirjasto. Kaikki oikeudet pidätetään."/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="fLK4q3SMlbeGTQl-tN32ENsBoaAaTlRd8sRbmTxlSBU" />

    <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="7EDEBF53A1C81ABECE44A7A666D94950" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Serif+Display&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-10360577-3', 'auto');
    </script>

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-KF8NK1STFH"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    // see google-analytics.service
</script>

<!-- Matomo -->

<script>
    var _paq = window._paq = window._paq || [];

    

    (function() {
            var u = "https://tilasto.lib.helsinki.fi/";
            _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u + 'matomo.php']);
            _paq.push(['setSiteId', '17']);
            var d = document, g = d.createElement('script'), s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            g.async = true;
            g.src = u + 'matomo.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
        }
    )();

</script>

<noscript><p><img src="https://tilasto.lib.helsinki.fi/matomo.php?idsite=17&amp;rec=1" style="border:0;" alt=""/></p></noscript>

<!-- End Matomo Code --><style type="text/css">[ng-cloak] { display: none !important; }</style>
    <script>
        window.errorHandlerUrl = "/rest/js-error-handler";
        window.commonOptions = {"localLoginEnabled":true,"localRegistrationEnabled":false,"marcOverlayEnabled":true,"opendataEnabled":true,"overrideHeader":"","hakaEnabled":true,"includeExternalResources":true,"legalDepositWorkstation":false,"jiraCollectorEnabled":true,"buildNumber":"8201672f226078f2cefbe8a0025dc03f5d98c25f","searchMaxResults":10000,"showExperimentalSearchFeatures":true,"bindingSearchMaxResults":1000,"excelDownloadEnabled":true,"giosgEnabled":true};
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">.external-resource-alt { display: none !important; }</style>
    </head>

<body class="digiweb">

    <noscript>
    <h3>Sovellus vaatii JavaScriptin.</h3>
    <p>Ole hyvä ja laita selaimesi JavaScript päälle, jos haluat käyttää palvelua.</p>
    <h3>Aktivera Javascript.</h3>
    <p>För att kunna använda våra webbaserade system behöver du ha Javascript aktiverat.</p>
    <h3>This application requires JavaScript.</h3>
    <p>Please turn on JavaScript in order to use the application.</p>
</noscript><app-digiweb></app-digiweb>

    <div id="kk-server-error" style="display: none;">
        <h1 align="center">Järjestelmässä tapahtui virhe.</h1></div>

    <div id="kk-server-page" style="display: none;">
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.language = "fi";
        window.renderId = 1672955582793;
        window.facebookAppId = "465149013631512"
        window.reCaptchaSiteKey = "6Lf7xuASAAAAANNu9xcDirXyzjebiH4pPpkKVCKq";
    </script>

    <script src="/assets/runtime-es2015.f1ac93cb35b9635f0f7e.js" type="module"></script>
            <script src="/assets/runtime-es5.f1ac93cb35b9635f0f7e.js" nomodule></script>
            <script src="/assets/polyfills-es2015.8db02cde19c51f542c72.js" type="module"></script>
            <script src="/assets/polyfills-es5.2273af7ef2cf66cdc0de.js" nomodule></script>
            <script src="/assets/styles-es2015.a539381f703344410705.js" type="module"></script>
            <script src="/assets/styles-es5.a539381f703344410705.js" nomodule></script>
            <script src="" type="module"></script>
            <script src="" type="module"></script>
            <script src="" nomodule></script>
            <script src="/assets/main-es2015.b5796f606e925a9d947d.js" type="module"></script>
            <script src="/assets/main-es5.b5796f606e925a9d947d.js" nomodule></script>
            </body>
</html>
```

Is there any better approach to initialize my `ORDER_BY` argument in bash to get rid of this error for the case no input is provided (initialize empty)?

Cheers,

Comment: It sounds like the API you're calling doesn't allow an empty string as the value of the `orderBy:` parameter. So use one of the valid orderings as the default instead of an empty string.

Comment: Side note 1: How about `key="${argument%%=*}"; value="${argument#*=}"` instead of an external process (`cut`)? Side note 2: Don’t use uppercase identifiers in Bash; they are reserved for environment variables by convention. Back to your question: …`${order_by:+\"orderBy\":\""${order_by}"\",}`… Read the _Expansions_ section of `man bash`; it’s long, but it’s well worth the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, you could replace

```
if [ -z "$ORDER_BY" ]; then ORDER_BY="${ORDER_BY:-}"; fi
```

with

```
if [ -z "$ORDER_BY" ]
then
    ORDER_BY=""
else
    ORDER_BY="\"orderBy\":\"$ORDER_BY\","
fi
```

and replace

```
"orderBy":"$ORDER_BY",
```

by

```
${ORDER_BY}
```

That would then pass the ORDER_BY directive in a context based manner and, if not present, would generate the output in the order items are encountered.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it fixed my problem! I just wonder if you could elaborate what the expression after `else` does practically? Also what you meant by `context based manner`?

Comment: With the end of the program modified to only contain the ${ORDER_BY} variable, the entire line which you previously had will simply NOT be included in the curl, but if there is a value for ${ORDER_BY}, then the full "clause" of your original line will be included in the curl.  The if gives either NO line or a FULL line.  "Context-based" refers to the fact that you have 2 scenarios, one with a value ... do one thing, one with no value ... do another thing.